# Array with names possible?

Tags: python

I am a bit lost with my code right now. The function takes some post_data and will login with this. What i am trying to do is to create a list / array that will have the name of the current post_data and the data itself , is this possible ?

Like this:

```
post_data = [('post_data1'={'user':'user1','pw':1234'}),('post_data2'={'user':'user2','pw':1234'})...]

def login_via(post_data):
...
print post_data[0]
...
```

I want to print the post_dataX and use the login data itself in a requests function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dict` instead of `tuple`:

```
post_data = [{
              'name': 'post_data1',
              'data': {'user':'user1','pw':'1234'}
             },
             {
              'name': 'post_data2',
              'data': {'user':'user2','pw':'1234'}
             }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
post_data = [{'post_data1':{'user':'user1','pw':1234}},{'post_data2':{'user':'user2','pw':1234}}]

def login_via(post_data):
    print post_data[0]

login_via(post_data)
>> {'post_data1': {'pw': 1234, 'user': 'user1'}}
```